# Compiler thinks variable is not assigned, but if statements cover all values

Tags: java, if-statement, flow-control

In this code there is a compile time error.

> "Example.java:17: error: variable y might not have been initialized".

Can anyone explain what's the reason for this error and how to fix it?

```
import java.util.*;
class Example{
  public static void main (String args[]){
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input an integer : ");
    int num=input.nextInt();
    int y;
    if(num>100){
      y=200;
    }
    if(num<100){
      y=200;
    }
    if(num==100){
      y=200;
    }
    System.out.println(y);
    
  }
}
```

Comment: you only initialize y in conditional blocks. your compiler will not go and check all your conditions to see if all scenario's are covered.

Comment: Convert that series of `if`s to `if-else if-else`

Comment: a simple `int y = 0;` solves the issue. The compiler does not know that your 3 `if`s cover all the cases.

Comment: The essential thing to understand: a compiler isn't a human. Albeit the compiler **could** figure out here that there is no path to the print *without* assigning a value to y ... well, it just doesn't.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca, thanks. it worked in if , else if and else series. but I relly need to understand why it works in if, if else , else and doesn't work in if series. because all the scenarios were covered in if series.

Comment: @Stultuske thanks. but when I used if, else if, else it executed. if compiler doesn't check all of that cases, how did it execute?  That's what I'm looking answers for.

Comment: @vichakshanadeegau because that's how [the language is defined](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-16.html). In particular see example 16-2. The compiler does not consider the possible values of `num`, only the structure of your code.

Comment: @GhostCat, thanks, then how did it executed when using a if, else if and else?

Comment: @vichakshanadeegau because of the difference between if and else. Now: if ( a > x || a == x || a < x ) -> this also covers all the possibilities, but the compiler won't know. if ( a > x ) { doOneThing(); } else { } -> always covers everything

Comment: @Stultuske strait to the point.. :-) thanks it helped a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before accessing a variable it must be initialized.

Static and instance variables are initialed implicitly even if you are not providing a value while declaring them. But with local variables, it's not the case, they must be assigned explicitly before you can use them.

You are not using **else** statement and it's not obvious to the compile that you've covered all possible cases.

Try this instead, you'll see that now variable **y** changes accordingly to the user input:

```
        int y;
        if (num < 100) {
            y=100;
        }
        else if (num > 100) {
            y=200;
        }
        else {
            y=300;
        }
```